Tried downloading an image file(QR Code) created using "next-qrcode". But not able to find what's wrong in the code
import { useQRCode } from "next-qrcode";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

const { Canvas } = useQRCode();

  const qrContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 const downloadQR = async () => {
    try {
      if (!qrContainerRef.current) {
        throw new Error("QR container element not found");
      }

      console.log("QR container element:", qrContainerRef.current);

      const canvas = await html2canvas(qrContainerRef.current);
      console.log("Captured Canvas:", canvas);

      const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      console.log("Data URL:", dataUrl);

      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = dataUrl;
      link.download = "qr-code.png";
      link.click();
      setDownloadError(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to download QR code:", error);
      setDownloadError("Failed to download QR code");
    }
  };

<div ref={qrContainerRef} style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <Canvas
          text={fullLink}
          options={{
            errorCorrectionLevel: "M",
            margin: 3,
            scale: 4,
            width: 200,
            color: {
              dark: "#010599FF",
              light: "#FFBF60FF",
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>

<button
                          className="flex items-center px-2 py-1 text-white transition rounded btn btn-secondary hover:opacity-70 bg-charcoal text-xs"
                          onClick={downloadQR}
                        >
                          Download QR
                          <Image
                            className="ml-2 w-4 h-4"
                            src={downloadImage}
                            alt="Download"
                          />
                        </button>

First, I have a link which is then converted to QR code using next-qrcode library which works fine.
The canvas element displays the QR code in UI.
But what I want to achieve is when clicked on download qr button, I want to download that QR code as an image.
I was able to get the image but it says this error. Also, the file size is 0 B, which may suggests that the QR code is not made into an image in the first place. Please help!!

